# How to disable dead keys in xkb (us / intl)

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I am using the US International layout on X11 (`-xkblayout us -xkbvariant intl`).

I would like to disable the dead keys, but *without* switching back to the US default layout. (I need the German Umlaute and a couple other characters from the Intl layout, I just don't care for the "dead" `~'"^.)

What would I need to do? Create a custom layout (like I did for Windows following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/280005/how-to-make-and-non-dead-keys-on-windows-7-with-german-keyboard-layout) excellent advice)? How would I do that? Or can I get the "no dead keys" behaviour in some easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a xkbvariant "altgr-intl" that puts the dead keys under the AltGr qualifier; i.e. while typing regularly, keys like `"` are not "dead". If you need them for international characters, you can type e.g. AltGr-" + e to get ë.

This particular layout is also [available for Windows](http://keyboards.jargon-file.org/altinter.zip).