# Dot instead of comma on numerical keyboard

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, keyboard-layout, key-binding

Using polish language on Windows 8.1, comma is the default decimal seperator on numerical keyboard. Is there a way to change it to dot?

I wouldn't like to change it in Excel or some other program, but *permanently rebind that key to dot*. Can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried changing your "Region and Language" settings?  There is a "Decimal Symbol" option which allows you to change the character(s) used. Control Panel > View by: Small/Large icons > Region and Language > Advanced Settings

Comment: @nonterrorist yes, I have. With no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it! It took "only" 2 years.

I used [Keyboard Layout Manager](http://www.klm32.com/) (unfortunately the website is down). After installing (run as admin!) click *New*, select new name, your language and your current layout as template. Then just change <kbd>,</kbd> on numpad to <kbd>.</kbd> and confirm with *Ok*.

In my case I removed the old layout from keyboards list, so only the new one remained. After this, the language bar dissappeared. But after logout/login it reappeared again and... everything worked as expected! Yay!

Also, no DLL for your new layout is generated so it only works locally on any given computer, it's not a portable solution. There is also a registration fee for this software, but a freeware version can handle dot/comma substitution.

Comment: Yes, this was also the only solution that worked for me. See also https://superuser.com/questions/280005/how-to-make-and-non-dead-keys-on-windows-7-with-german-keyboard-layout on how to remove the backtick or accents

Comment: Dead link - site does not exist anymore. Google finds download links on fishy sources (informer, softpedia ...)

Answer (score 17):

You can do this using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) with the following simple script:

```
NumpadDot::.
```

Basically, because Windows is interpreting the number pad's `.` signal as a `,` in the Polish layout, you just have to rebind that keystroke to the standard keyboard's `.` command again.

You could also try the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665).

Comment: This options seems only to work when this program (AutoHotKey) is open... :/

Comment: @snoram yes and that is not an issue.

Comment: the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator did the job

Comment: Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator also did the job for me. It's a bit sloppy and counterintuitive on Windows 10, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: AutoHotKey works brilliantly!

Answer (score 16):

I think the same problem sits in the German version of Windows 8. This way it is really annoying for example to enter a date or decimal number in Excel. The Numberpad becomes totally useless.

The Solution (sorry for German screenshots):

1. Open **Control Panel** (*Systemsteuerung*) with rightclick on the windows
   icon in the lower left corner of your screen.
2. Select the shortcut to change the format of **Date, Time and Numbers** (*Datums-, Uhrzeit- oder Zahlenformat ändern*): [image: Control Panel]
3. Choose the **Advanced Settings** (*Weitere Einstellungen*): [image: Region Settings]
4. Type in a **dot** instead of the **comma** (*Dezimaltrennzeichen* Komma --> Punkt): [image: Change Format]
5. Repeat step 4 for the **Currency** (*Währung*) tab.
6. Confirm changes with **OK**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately, this solution does not work. numpad dot still gives comma.

Comment: Try changing the decimal separator to the dot in the currency tab as well.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 8.1 with German(Swiss) Keyboard.

Comment: Didn't work on Icelandic keyboard.

Comment: Unforunately didn't work for me either (french belgian keyboard, win10); but I've found [another solution](http://superuser.com/a/1119351/202725).

Comment: these settings does not seem to change the keyboard behavior. Only the Excel-like programs, it seems. But when I press the "dot" on the numerical keyboard, I still have the  ".", not "comma", as it is in these settings.

Answer (score 15):

Solved this in Windows 10 with Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134

It requires .Net Framework 2.0, but I have latest 4.8.

1. Open Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator. I got some errors, but
   just pressed "Ignore" all time.
2. File > Load existing Keyboard
   (find your current)
3. Change comma to dot here:
   [image]

3b. Adjust fields in Project > Properties

4. Press Project > Validate Layout and fix issues. In Russian case I deleted Alt+Ctrl+8 currency symbol (I didn`t even know it exists in default).
5. Press Project > Build DLL and Setup package.
6. Run `setup.exe` from build folder.
7. Press `magnifier` icon and type `language` > go to "Language and Keyboard Settings".
8. Select bottom "language package available" version and press `arrow up` till it will be upper than yours previous layout.
9. After that delete your previous language.
10. In my case language bar in tray dissapeared after previous step, so I used this https://winaero.com/blog/enable-language-bar-windows-10/
11. Reboot your PC.

Comment: update the first link, it does not work anymore

Comment: Thank you, fixed

Answer (score 4):

The utility [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) manipulates the windows ScancodeMap registry key, which can map any key to any other key.  You don't need to know the scancodes, SharpKeys figures them out for you.  You just press the key you want to remap, and press the key you want to map it to, and it will write it to the registry. SharpKeys doesn't run in the background - the registry key that it uses is part of Windows.

Unfortunately, it's not documented to work on Windows 8, and not guaranteed 100% on non-US keyboards, but the underlying Windows registry key will still be there, so there is a good chance it will work, and it almost certainly won't hurt to try.

Comment: utility seems promising, but the installer doesn't even start on win 8.1

Comment: I have extracted the installer using "Universal Extractor" (it used the MSI Administrative Command Line unpack method), I ran the application and I have mapped my NUM_DEL to KEY_DOT_> (or something like that). IT WORKS. THANKS! (also, no need to reboot, logging out and in seems to be enough for the changes to apply). If you do not want to download an additional utility to extract the .msi, check out [this](http://thebackroomtech.com/2007/08/23/howto-extract-files-from-a-msi-file-using-the-windows-command-line/) link.

Comment: Great! Worked smoothly.

Comment: Finally, this worked for me. Only one issue: it works the other way round than I expected. Maps from right to left, not left to right.

Answer (score 4):

[Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339)

Worked for making a Swedish keyboard numpad produce dot instead of comma.

Brief overview for Windows 10:

- install and run downloaded app.
- load existing keyboard (option in the menu)
- modify and "Save as..."
- generate installer (option in the menu)
- run installer
- reboot

At this point press Win+Space,
and select your new keyboard layout.

Comment: This is from 2007. Does not seem to work on Win10 anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a clean solution for my French (Belgian) keyboard in Windows 10.

1. In the Windows menu, search for "keyboard options"
   [image: In the Windows menu, search for "keyboard options"]
2. Under "Languages", click on your keyboard's language and select "Options"
   [image: Under "Languages", click on your keyboard's language and select "Options"]
3. There, under "Keyboard", I see my current keyboard as "Belgian **(Comma)**".  Click on "Add a keyboard" and select the same keyboard but ending with "**(Period)**".
   [image: Click on "Add a keyboard" and select the same keyboard but ending with "(Period)"]
4. Eventually remove the previous "Comma" keyboard to make sure you always use the "Period" one.
   [image: Eventually remove the previous "Comma" keyboard to make sure you always use the "Period" one]
5. Voilà.  <kbd>.</kbd> now properly prints `.` !

Comment: From what I can see only Belgian has keyboards with comma/period, there's no such choice for other languages.

Comment: I have french keyboard, there is not such an option for French

Answer (score 1):

I changed my keyboard to English (US) which fixed it for me.

Control Panel/Clock language and region/Change input methods

Answer (score 1):

I use Hungarian QWERTZ layout (102) but Win 10 has no option for having dot on the numpad instead of a comma (Hungarian decimal symbol). Typing IP addresses is a real pain this way.

Of course my decimal should stay comma, so modifying local and currency settings is no solution. Having a 3rd party app for this feels like an overkill for me. But this solution with registry override worked for me like charm: [Rebinding Numpad . (location 104) to regular dot (location 54)](https://superuser.com/questions/1173975/rebinding-numpad-location-104-to-regular-dot-location-54?rq=1)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,34,00,53,00,00,00,00,00
```

Save this to a file named `102to102dot.reg` (only the extension matters), run it and add the key to the registry. After reboot, it works as expected. To undo it, simply remove the `Scancode Map` key from the registry path above in RegEdit.

Comment: This is a lifesaver, works like a charm without external dependencies. OFF: I think the decimal separator comma is ugly, so I use dot in Hungarian text too.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Windows 10, I was able to modify the key behavior without any 3rd party software, through the following menu: **Typing settings** > **Advanced keyboard settings** > **Override the default input method**.

[image: Windows 10 Advanced keyboard settings]

In my case, it allowed switching between period and comma versions of my keyboard layout (French Belgium).

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:
**SharpKeys** https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys ,
it is now also available on MS Store: https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/sharpkeys/XPFFCG7M673D4F