# Windows 10 calculator and regional settings

Tags: windows-10, calculator

I have Windows 10 with English lanugage.
In regional settings I have set Denmark and my keyboard is Danish.

The Windows Calculator (calc.exe) seems to have switched "." and ",", like used in USA. When I enter "," on my keyboard it writes ".".
, and . works as expected in other programs like Excel.

Is this just the way the Windows 10 calculator behaves or can I change it?

Comment: I'm not sure if [this is what you want](http://superuser.com/q/747250/167187), but it might be relevant.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have already checked choose settings, so that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a problem with the calculator in Windows 10 that hasn't been fixed yet. What I did was [install the Windows 7/8 calculator](http://winaero.com/blog/get-calculator-from-windows-8-and-windows-7-in-windows-10/).

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the article in your answer in case the link breaks.