# How can I change a comma to period on a numerical keyboard on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

How can I change a comma to a period on numerical keyboard on Windows 10 without changing the input language?

When I used Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator the keyboard created wasn’t shown in available keyboard in input methods in “Control Panel -> Clock, Language and Region -> Language -> Language” options although it did work on Windows 7.

Is there any other way I can change it?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/747250/dot-instead-of-comma-on-numerical-keyboard) SU question which may relate. It's backwards for him, so I'll sum it up:

1. Press <kbd>Win+R</kbd> and run `control intl.cpl`
2. Click Additional Settings

   [image]
3. Change the Decimal Symbol from a Comma to a Period in both the `Numbers` and `Currency` Tabs

[image]

4. (**Optional**) Since I'm honestly not too familiar with foreign keyboards, you could try changing the `List Separator` value on both tabs and see if that helps you.

---

Use the following **[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)** script to rebind the numeric-key comma to a period:

```
Numpaddot::.
```

Use the following **[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)** script to rebind the all comma keys (not just numeric one) to a period:

```
,::.
```

[image] [image]

Comment: I installed AutoHotkey and run the code but there's no change. there's still coma. And apart from that the AH icon is now in the taskbar. Does it mean I have to run this script every time I start the computer?

Comment: You would need to right click on the script and compile it, then it becomes an `.exe`. Then you put the `.exe` in your Startup folder so yes, it would need to run every time.

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried the "Auto hotkey" solution, It might not work. 
I've tried many suggestions myself, including the one suggested by 'insane'. But non worked for me, until I found this on the AHK forum.

```
Numpaddot::
SendInput, ,
```

Comment: It rebinds to comma. @kaczka03 asked for regind to dot.