# Windows 10 changed how quotation marks work. How do I fix this?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I've always been used to pressing the `'` and `"` button **twice** to get the respective characters. But recently, it changed without my involvement.

Now, when I press the button, I get 2 of them immediately. Aside from being just a pain in the gluteus maximus, it also doesn't allow me to type apostrophe characters.

I don't know when this started, but I believe it had something to do with the last big update, which required rebooting several times. Since this might be an intended feature by Microsoft, I don't know if it's fixable, so any and all answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Which characters need apostrophes? Or do you mean accents? Check the keyboard layout first.

Comment: I mean characters like these --> é. It's not on my keyboard

Comment: Yeah, that's an accent and done with the accent button. Apostrophe is completely different, though many people abuse accents as apostrophes :G ` and ´ vs '

Comment: I hope I'm not expected to call everything by it's correct name, seeing as I'm Dutch. I'd still like to be able to type these characters

Comment: No, of course not. Just making sure people know exactly what buttons are being talked about :)

Comment: I actually wasn't sure how to call them, so I tried referring to them as buttons, rather than characters

Comment: Are you using a laptop keyboard/touchscreen or one that is connected by cable?

Comment: @jatuttle0 I am on a laptop with a built in keyboard and trackpad.

Comment: just load the correct keyboard layout you use, or use [MKLC](https://superuser.com/q/280005/241386) and add the dead keys if they're not available

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you’re currently using the “US – QWERTY” layout. What you probably want is the [US International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#US-International) keyboard. It has all the so-called “dead keys” you want:

> - <kbd>'</kbd> + vowel → vowel with acute accent, e.g., <kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> → é
> - <kbd>`</kbd> + vowel → vowel with grave accent, e.g., <kbd>`</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> → è
> - <kbd>"</kbd> + vowel → vowel with diaeresis (or umlaut), e.g., <kbd>"</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> → ë
> - <kbd>^</kbd> + vowel → vowel with circumflex accent, e.g., <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> → ê
> - <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>o</kbd> → letter with tilde, e.g. <kbd>~</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> → ñ, <kbd>~</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> → õ
> - <kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> → ç (Windows)

To enable it, go to Settings → Time & language → Region & language (sidebar). There, select the language (English, Dutch, whatever) you want to modify, click “Options”. Then, under “Keyboards” add the “United Status-International” layout. Then remove the regular US layout.

Comment: I tried this (changed setting and rebooted), but it didn't work. I actually changed all my languages to the United States-International qwerty, but no luck with this either

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D it fixed the quotation mark problem of my keyboard. I had to press twice in a row to get two ' ' (instead of once to get one ') which bothered me many days. Now it's back to normal

Comment: This solution didn't work at all for me. Please help!

Comment: If you want to just get the character ie `'` you can follow it with a space.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 10, go to Languages, click your preferred language (English) and then Options. Ensure that United States QWERTY keyboard is being used instead of United States-International QWERTY. Add it if you need to. Delete the international keyboard and Viola! No more annoying accents.

Comment: This appears to be the opposite of what the OP asked & already has an answer [though not accepted]